# How to use the ScrollView in Kivy?

Tags: python, scroll, kivy, scrollview, kivy-language

I want to create a scroll view in a specific part of the screen.
The number of contents that will be in the view can change - therefor I want to insert the widgets to the view via a for a loop.

[This is how the view is going to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uboxs.png)
I am struggling for a while with this issue.
I can't seem to:

1. Insert the Widgets to the view with a for loop
2. Place the view in a specific location.

`

```
class PlaylistWidget(ScrollView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PlaylistWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bar_width = 50
        self.size_hint = 1, .1
        self.scroll_type = ['bars']
        self.bar_inactive_color = 5, 20, 10, .5
        self.bar_color = 5, 10, 15, .8
        self.do_scroll_x = False
        self.do_scroll_y = True

        grid = GridLayout()
        grid.height = self.size[1]
        grid.size_hint_y = None
        grid.cols = 1
        grid.row_default_height = '20dp'
        grid.row_force_default = True

        for i in range(148):
            a = Label()
            a.text = "Blah blah blah"
            a.font_size = 30
            a.size_hint_y = None
            a.size_hint_x = 1.0
            a.height = self.size[1]

            grid.add_widget(a)

        self.add_widget(grid)
```

`
this is a try code that i did....

Thx.
Ofek Harel.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you are missing is that you must set the heights of each `Label` that you add to the `GridLayout`, and you must also set the height of the `GridLayout`. Here is a modified version of you code that does that:

```
class PlaylistWidget(ScrollView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PlaylistWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bar_width = 50
        self.size_hint = 1, .1
        self.scroll_type = ['bars']
        self.bar_inactive_color = 5, 20, 10, .5
        self.bar_color = 5, 10, 15, .8
        self.do_scroll_x = False
        self.do_scroll_y = True

        grid = GridLayout()

        # star with zero height
        grid.height = 0

        grid.size_hint_y = None
        grid.cols = 1
        grid.row_default_height = '20dp'
        grid.row_force_default = True

        for i in range(148):
            a = Label()
            a.text = "Blah blah blah"
            a.font_size = 30
            a.size_hint_y = None
            a.size_hint_x = 1.0

            # set label height
            a.height = grid.row_default_height

            # increment grid height
            grid.height += a.height

            grid.add_widget(a)

        self.add_widget(grid)
```

Another way is to use the kivy language to set up the `ScrollView`. This approach takes advantage of the `minimum_height` that the `GridLayout` calculates, so that you don't have to calculate the `height` of the `GridLayout`:

```
class PlaylistWidget(ScrollView):
    def add_labels(self, *args):
        grid = self.ids.grid
        for i in range(148):
            a = Label()
            a.text = "Blah blah blah"
            a.font_size = 30
            a.size_hint_y = None
            a.size_hint_x = 1.0

            # set label height
            a.height = grid.row_default_height

            grid.add_widget(a)


kv = '''
PlaylistWidget:
    bar_width: 50
    size_hint: 1, .1
    scroll_type: ['bars']
    bar_inactive_color: 5, 20, 10, .5
    bar_color: 5, 10, 15, .8
    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 1
        row_default_height: '20dp'
        row_force_default: True
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
'''


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pl = Builder.load_string(kv)
        Clock.schedule_once(pl.add_labels)
        return pl

TestApp().run()
```